# Rider plugin create new class in another namespace

Tags: c#, plugins, rider

I'm trying to write a plugin for Rider (C#) where I want to create a unit test class for any given class.

I've tried making an Action, and through the IDataContext able to pull out the class name and find the test project/assembly. So I have all the information to create the unit test class.
I just can't find any examples on how to create a new C# class and place it in the given test project/assembly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.